# QML can't open file dialog

Tags: file, dialog, qml

I'm trying to create a simple File dialog using the QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Please choose a file"
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + fileDialog.fileUrls)
        Qt.quit()
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
        Qt.quit()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```

However, when I try to preview it I receive following errors/warnings:

```
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
Invalid URL:  QUrl( "" ) 
Invalid URL:  QUrl( "" ) 
Invalid URL:  QUrl( "" ) 
Invalid URL:  QUrl( "" ) 
kf5.kio.core: KLocalSocket(0x1a51cf0) Jumbo packet of 35946 bytes
```

As far as I understand, settings the QUrl is not needed to display the dialog. If so, is it possible to set it to the user's home folder in a cross-platform way? I also tried to start the ibus daemon as I found on google that it's causing that first error line but it's still not working.

I'm using Arch (fully updated) with KF5 and QT5.4 installed.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with KF5, or rather with the interaction between QML FileDialog and KDE's platform dialog, see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=334963. It doesn't look like it's resolved yet.

You can work around this (and get the dialog to show) by adding "modality: Qt.NonModal" to the FileDialog.